# split a column to a few columns by conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 3 tables.

- `company_report` (old_product_code,count)
- `dictionary`(old_product_code, new_product_code)
- `myreport`(new_product_code, package_of_1, package_of_3, package_of_5)

In my `company_report` table I have sometimes 2 or 3 `old_product_code` that fit to one `new_product_code`

The result I want is `my_report` table.

A picture of an example attached.

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want a join with conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  d.new_product_code,
  Package1 = SUM(CASE WHEN REPLACE(cr.old_product_code, d.new_product_code, '') = '1' THEN count END),
  Package3 = SUM(CASE WHEN REPLACE(cr.old_product_code, d.new_product_code, '') = '3' THEN count END),
  Package5 = SUM(CASE WHEN REPLACE(cr.old_product_code, d.new_product_code, '') = '5' THEN count END)
FROM company_report cr
JOIN dictionary d ON d.old_product_code = cr.old_product_code
GROUP BY
  d.new_product_code;
```

Comment: Its not working. it give me " null" values in all the fields.

Comment: Presumably there is something not quite matching up with your data. Please [edit] your question and give actual sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.new_code 
,case when SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))='1' then count end as package_1
,case when SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))='3' then count end as package_3
,case when SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))='5' then count end as package_5
from dictionary d
left join company_report c
on d.old_code=c.old_product_code
group by d.new_code
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is going to get an aggregation error on those three columns, because of the `GROUP BY`. You are probably missing `SUM()`